I want to add a push notification based on the user selection at the schedule to any device that logged on to the account
i would like to ask a question, i want to add a push notification at my TypeScript Next.js 14.2 for every selection at Penjadwalan (translate: Schedule), like i want it to send a push notification for 1 time in a day and much more based on the user select, can i get a recommendation or solving for this?
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { FieldValues, SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useSupabaseClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useUser } from "@/hooks/useUser";

const svg = {
  userDarken: require("@/shared/icons/user-darken.svg"),
  pillDarken: require("@/shared/icons/pill-darken.svg"),
  calendarPlusDarken: require("@/shared/icons/calendar-plus-darken.svg"),
  vaccineBottleDarken: require("@/shared/icons/vaccine-bottle-darken.svg"),
  bellPlusDarken: require("@/shared/icons/bell-plus-darken.svg"),
  checkupListDarken: require("@/shared/icons/checkup-list-darken.svg"),
  plusSecondary: require("@/shared/icons/plus-secondary.svg"),
  xSecondary: require("@/shared/icons/x-secondary.svg"),
};

interface AddProviderProps {
  className: string;
  onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}

const ComponentAddProvider: React.FC<AddProviderProps> = ({
  className,
  onClick,
}) => {
  const [controlExpand, setControlExpand] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const supabaseClient = useSupabaseClient();
  const router = useRouter();
  const { user } = useUser();

  useEffect(() => {
    const controlExpandBreakpoint = window.innerWidth < 1024;
    setControlExpand(!controlExpandBreakpoint);
  }, []);

  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm<FieldValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      date_added: new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0],
      patient: "",
      medicine: "",
      dosage: "",
      dosage_unit: "Pilih Dosis",
      schedule: "Pilih Penjadwalan",
      notes: "",
    },
  });

  const eventSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = async (values) => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);

      const { error: supabaseError } = await supabaseClient
        .from("reminders")
        .insert({
          user_id: user?.id,
          date_added: values.date_added,
          patient: values.patient,
          medicine: values.medicine,
          dosage: values.dosage,
          dosage_unit: values.dosage_unit,
          schedule: values.schedule,
          notes: values.notes,
        });

      if (supabaseError) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(supabaseError.message);
      }

      router.refresh();
      reset();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(eventSubmit)}
      className={`bg-[hsl(210,17%,98%)] ${className} z-10 w-full lg:w-[480px] px-6 py-0 lg:p-8 rounded-3xl`}
    >
      <div
        className={`${
          controlExpand ? "mt-0 mb-4 lg:mb-8" : "m-0"
        } flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-start justify-between w-full h-auto`}
      >
        <div className="z-10 flex flex-col items-center lg:items-start justify-center lg:justify-start w-full lg:w-auto h-auto">
          <p className="text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] font-medium text-sm text-start mt-0 mb-0">
            Tambahkan Pengingat
          </p>
          <p className="text-[hsl(0,0%,53%)] font-light text-xs text-start mt-0 mb-0">
            Buat Penjadwalan Sekarang
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-row gap-4 lg:gap-2 items-center justify-center lg:justify-end w-full lg:w-auto h-auto mt-4 lg:mt-0">
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="bg-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] opacity-100 transition-all hover:opacity-80 flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-center w-full lg:w-fit p-4 lg:px-4 lg:py-2 rounded-2xl"
          >
            <Image
              src={svg.plusSecondary}
              width="14"
              height="14"
              alt="plusSecondary"
            />
            <p className="text-[hsl(210,17%,98%)] font-medium text-xs">
              Tambah
            </p>
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={onClick}
            className="bg-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] opacity-100 transition-all hover:opacity-80 flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-center w-full lg:w-fit p-4 lg:px-4 lg:py-2 rounded-2xl"
          >
            <Image
              src={svg.xSecondary}
              width="14"
              height="14"
              alt="xSecondary"
            />
            <p className="text-[hsl(210,17%,98%)] font-medium text-xs">
              Keluar
            </p>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-auto gap-4 mt-4 lg:mt-8">
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center justify-center gap-2 w-full h-auto">
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-start w-full lg:w-[60%] h-auto p-0 mt-0">
            <Image
              src={svg.calendarPlusDarken}
              width="16"
              height="16"
              alt="calendarPlusDarken"
            />
            <p className="text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] font-medium text-xs text-start mt-0">
              Ditambahkan Pada
            </p>
          </div>
          <input
            id="date_added"
            {...register("date_added", { required: true })}
            disabled={isLoading}
            type="date"
            placeholder="Masukkan Nama Obat .."
            className="outline-none bg-transparent text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] placeholder:text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)]/60 w-full font-light text-xs"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center justify-center gap-2 w-full h-auto">
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-start w-full lg:w-[60%] h-auto p-0 mt-0">
            <Image
              src={svg.userDarken}
              width="16"
              height="16"
              alt="userDarken"
            />
            <p className="text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] font-medium text-xs text-start mt-0">
              Nama Pasien
            </p>
          </div>
          <input
            id="patient"
            {...register("patient", { required: true })}
            disabled={isLoading}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Masukkan Nama Pasien .."
            className="outline-none bg-transparent text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] placeholder:text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)]/60 w-full font-light text-xs"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center justify-center gap-2 w-full h-auto">
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-start w-full lg:w-[60%] h-auto p-0 mt-0">
            <Image
              src={svg.pillDarken}
              width="16"
              height="16"
              alt="pillDarken"
            />
            <p className="text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] font-medium text-xs text-start mt-0">
              Obat
            </p>
          </div>
          <input
            id="medicine"
            {...register("medicine", { required: true })}
            disabled={isLoading}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Masukkan Nama Obat .."
            className="outline-none bg-transparent text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] placeholder:text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)]/60 w-full font-light text-xs"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center justify-center gap-2 w-full h-auto">
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-start w-full lg:w-[60%] h-auto p-0 mt-0">
            <Image
              src={svg.vaccineBottleDarken}
              width="16"
              height="16"
              alt="vaccineBottleDarken"
            />
            <p className="text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] font-medium text-xs text-start mt-0">
              Dosis
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-start w-full h-auto">
            <input
              id="dosage"
              {...register("dosage", { required: true })}
              disabled={isLoading}
              type="number"
              placeholder="Masukkan Dosis .."
              className="outline-none bg-transparent text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] placeholder:text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)]/60 w-full font-light text-xs"
            />
            <select
              id="dosage_unit"
              {...register("dosage_unit", { required: true })}
              disabled={isLoading}
              className="outline-none bg-transparent text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] placeholder:text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)]/60 w-full font-light text-xs"
            >
              <option>Pilih Satuan</option>
              <option id="miligram">Miligram (mg)</option>
              <option id="mikrogram">Mikrogram (µg)</option>
              <option id="milliliter">
                Milliliter (ml) atau Cubic Centimeter (cc)
              </option>
              <option id="unit">Unit (U)</option>
              <option id="gram">Gram (g)</option>
              <option id="international_unit">International Unit (IU)</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center justify-center gap-2 w-full h-auto">
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-start w-full lg:w-[60%] h-auto p-0 mt-0">
            <Image
              src={svg.bellPlusDarken}
              width="16"
              height="16"
              alt="bellPlusDarken"
            />
            <p className="text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] font-medium text-xs text-start mt-0">
              Penjadwalan
            </p>
          </div>
          <select
            id="schedule"
            {...register("schedule", { required: true })}
            disabled={isLoading}
            className="outline-none bg-transparent text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] placeholder:text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)]/60 w-full font-light text-xs"
          >
            <option>Pilih Penjadwalan</option>
            <option id="one_time_in_a_day">1x Sehari</option>
            <option id="two_time_in_a_day">2x Sehari</option>
            <option id="three_time_in_a_day">3x Sehari</option>
            <option id="one_time_in_a_week">1x Seminggu</option>
            <option id="one_time_in_a_week">2x Seminggu</option>
            <option id="one_time_in_a_week">3x Seminggu</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center justify-center gap-2 w-full h-auto">
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center justify-start w-full lg:w-[60%] h-auto p-0 mt-0">
            <Image
              src={svg.checkupListDarken}
              width="16"
              height="16"
              alt="checkupListDarken"
            />
            <p className="text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] font-medium text-xs text-start mt-0">
              Keterangan
            </p>
          </div>
          <input
            id="notes"
            {...register("notes", { required: false })}
            disabled={isLoading}
            type="text"
            placeholder="(Opsional) Masukkan Keterangan .."
            className="outline-none bg-transparent text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)] placeholder:text-[hsl(0,0%,13%)]/60 w-full font-light text-xs"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ComponentAddProvider;

I just dont know what kind of npm modules to use, or if there's anybody can help me to solve it?
